# openFDA: Is there any way to match NDC data in different format?

Tags: api, data.gov, openfda, data-format

I'd like to know whether or not there is a possible way to match NDC codes in different formats by using openFDA API like Recall Enforcement Reports. For example,  matching 0187-0798-30 with 0187-079-830 but without the hyphen, it is the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple regular expression, you can convert the NDC number to the expected format and then query the API.